# localizar modal

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

la duda es: cerrar la modal o que encuentre el texto dentro de la modal, debido a esto, podríamos rellenar futuros formularios dentro de una modal. La ruta de la prueba es est@: https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/entry_ad

```
        @Test
        public void navigate() throws InterruptedException {
            
            driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/entry_ad");
            
            WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//h3)[1]"));
            assertEquals("Entry Ad", title.getText());
            System.out.println(title.getText());
            WebElement clickModal = driver.findElement(By.id("restart-ad"));
    //pulsamos para que muestre la modal
            clickModal.click();
            
        //String titleModal = 
//  js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('modal').style.display ='block';").toString();
          // localizo el texto del xpath
            WebElement titleModal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//h3)[2]"));
            System.out.println( titleModal.getText());
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//p)[5]")).click();
        }
```

Comment: ¿cuál es la pregunta/problema?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo localizar una modal con formulario?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375113/c%c3%b3mo-localizar-una-modal-con-formulario)

Comment: La pregunta es: cerrar la modal o que encuentre el texto dentro de la modal, debido a esto solución podríamos rellenar futuras formularios dentro de modales.